# Using an "AS" clause in a sub-query than contains a "WHERE" clause

Tags: ms-access

I want to store result in the variable generated by using "AS" clause in the MS Access,
and use this result in the sub-query with WHERE clause.

I tried this:

```
SELECT en_date AS date_en, (select sum(amount) 
  from main where
    CrDb='Cr'
  and
    en_date=date_en) AS CR_AMT
FROM main
GROUP BY en_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select m.en_date date_en, sum(m.amount)
from main m
where CrDb = 'Cr'
group by m.en_date
```

In other words, I dont think you even need a sub-query to get the results you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain you can't use an alias (the AS destination) in the same SELECT you defined it in.

I can't tell quite what you're trying to do, but it kind of looks like you want to be joining the table to itself.

Comment: In Access (ACE, Jet, whatever), one can use an `AS` clause within the  same `SELECT` clause in the same scope in which it is defined e.g. `SELECT 2 AS two, two + two AS four;` is legal (bizarrely though can't be used in the `ORDER BY` clause).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    en_date,
    SUM(amount)
FROM
    main a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        en_date AS date_en,
        CrDb
    FROM
        main 
    WHERE
        CrDb='Cr'
)b
ON
    a.en_date = b.date_en
    AND a.CrDb = b.CrDb
GROUP BY
    en_date
```